# При попытке добавления события Yandex Metrika выдаёт Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-metrika-api

Вот код:

```
   $("a .btn-green .js-order-product").bind("click") , function() {
            yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('korzina');
        };
```

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: yaCounterXXXXXX верно прописали? Номер XXXXXX совпадает с номером в скрипте метрики?

Comment: Да, перепроверял. Это может быть потому что метрика старая не удалена?

Comment: Что, при клике, пишет консоль? Есть ли, при клике, какие-нибудь запросы во вкладке Network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполнил внутреннюю часть через javascript. Всё работает.

```
if ($("button#checkoutFormSubmit span").text() == 'Подтвердить заказ') {
        var button = document.querySelector("button#checkoutFormSubmit span");
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
              yaCounterХХХХХ.reachGoal('zakaz_button');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Не читаются символы { и } Окружите код скрипта тегами {literal}...{/literal}